# Authorizing Google service account with JWT for Gmail API

Tags: jwt, python-3.6, google-api-python-client

I am trying to access my emails through Gmail API (through AWS lambda), using service account credentials. I do not have a GSuite account, so I cannot delegate domain-wide authority and impersonate my user@gmail.com account.

I resorted to Service account authorization without OAuth, using a signed JWT directly as a bearer token. [see]: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth

I also enabled all access to Gmail to the application and made service account an owner role in the console.

I am using **google.auth.jwt** module, but struggle to understand the documentation fully: [see docs]: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.jwt.html#module-google.auth.jwt

This is what I tried:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from google.auth import crypt
from google.auth import jwt

audience = 'https://mail.google.com/' ## full access scope
credentials = jwt.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'credentials.json', audience=audience) # json credentials from api console - for service account
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

This gives me a 401 error:

```py
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json returned "Invalid Credentials">
```

`credentials` object return appears as valid, with all necessary elements, however, I don't know how to make it "impersonate" my personal email.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid credentails normally means that the credentials.json is not the correct type for the code you are using.

Make sure that you have downloaded the credentials.json for a service account.